# Write stata dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, stata

I've created a dataframe in R, and I am trying to convert it to .dta to use it in Stata. I feel like it should be straightforward, but I keep getting an error that says "empty string is not valid in Stata's documented format". I have been trying to use write.dta from the foreign package.

Comment: See the update to the accepted answer, suggesting use of `haven::write_dta`.

Comment: The foreign package is no longer being maintained. The help page of 'write.dta' also states: "Frozen: will not support Stata formats after 10 (also used by Stata 11)."